# Deliver a Facebook Messenger response to the user based on a postback event in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postback, webhooks, facebook-messenger, payload

we’re getting into some troubles regarding our code and no way to find someone who has already faced the exact same problem with Rails.

We are trying to implement a facebook messengr chatbot in Rails and we’re already stucked at the first step. We’ve tried to implement a get started button and, as the action of clicking onto this button sends a postback event to the webhook, try to deliver a response to this event that would be a reply to the user (with quick replies).

```
bot-messenger/bot/bot.rb

Facebook::Messenger::Profile.set({
   get_started: {
     payload: 'LETS_START'
   }
 }, access_token: ENV['ACCESS_TOKEN'])


Bot.on :postback do |postback|
  postback.sender    # => { 'id' => '1008372609250235' }
  postback.recipient # => { 'id' => '2015573629214912' }
  postback.sent_at   # => 2016-04-22 21:30:36 +0200

 if postback.payload == "LETS_START"
    postback.deliver(
      message: {
        text: "Hi! I'm your bot. How do you feel today?"
        quick_replies: [
        {
          content_type: 'text',
          title: 'Sévèrement stressé(e)!',
          payload: 'SEVERELY_STRESSED'
        },
        {
          content_type: 'text',
          title: 'Moyennement stressé(e)!',
          payload: 'SOMEWHAT_STRESSED'
        },
        {
          content_type: 'text',
          title: 'Peu/pas stressé(e)!',
          payload: 'NOT_STRESSED'
        }
        ]
      }
    )
  end

  if message.payload == "SEVERELY_STRESSED" || "SOMEWHAT_STRESSED"
    puts "quite bad"
  elsif postback.payload == "NOT_STRESSED"
    puts "cool"
  end
end
```

When restarting our conversation with the bot, the get started button appears properly but after clicking on it, nothing happens. Could you please help?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Check what 'postback.payload' returns

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to set up a webhook url pointing to your server. See [official documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/webhook-setup). If you develop your bot on local you can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to route incoming webhooks from Facebook to your local machine. Ngrok shows you all incoming request with HTTP payload so then you can adjust your code accordingly.